# How to push tags to Github via GitKraken

Tags: git, github, git-bash, gitkraken

I have a fully working connection between a paid Pro version of GitKraken, connected to Github using a SSH key.

Now, pushing a "tag", as explained [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_sharing_tags), is NOT defaultly done via "normal" push.

> By default, the git push command doesn’t transfer tags to remote servers. You will have to explicitly push tags to a shared server after you have created them.

To be clear to all readers, I intend to use a "tag" to identify each release version number on its specific commit.

So the suggested solution of the above linked explanation is a command line one.

- I tried using the GitKraken terminal... The connection is denied.
- I tried Git Bash to acces a command line... Maybe it would work, but I need a SSH key specific to Git Bash.
- I tried to create one [following the steps of this tutorial](https://www.targetprocess.com/guide/integrations/integrations-source-control/issue-ssh-key-pair-from-git-bash-use-in-targetprocess/) but it isn't accepted by Github. I got an error message saying the key is invalid, use an OpenSSH key.

Hey... I'm sure that pushing a tag is easier than all that. Awaiting your advises!

Comment: The same `git push` command-line command that pushes commits also pushes tags. There's nothing special required - no different key, for instance - other than to say "hey Git, push this tag". Git*Hub*, on the other hand, can be set to *reject* certain push requests, by any admin, for any user, for any reason. Perhaps your admin has set things up so that you are not allowed to create tags.

Comment: Note that when you use ssh with Git, Git simply *runs ssh*. Git doesn't have its own private ssh. There's a special case with Git-for-WIndows: it's *bundled with* an ssh in case your Windows system is lacking in ssh capabilities. So sometimes on a Windows install, you have to tell Git (with `git config core.sshCommand`) which ssh to run. But it just runs *an* ssh, so just make it run the ssh that's already working for GitKraken, as long as GitKraken didn't build ssh in and make it unusable by other programs.

Comment: (I've never used GitKraken myself so I'm not sure if it's one of those unfriendly closed systems. Programs should be usable by other programs, so that they become modular, but not everyone agrees with this idea.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can push commits with GitKraken, then right-clicking on an ***annotated*** tag and selecting "`Push <tag-name> to origin`" should be enough.

[image: https://1v5ymx3zt3y73fq5gy23rtnc-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/git-push-tag-to-remote-gitkraken.png.webp]

See "[GitKraken / Git Push Tag](https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/problems/git-push-tag)".

If pushing in general is denied because of SSH issue, check your [GitHub authentication preference in GitKraken](https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/github/#github-authentication).

Comment: Really!!?! It is just a right-click on the tag itself!! lollllll! I lost so much time on this and never tried a right click directly on it. Wow... Well Thanks a big lot!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  No problem. You are most welcome.